# Is it undefined behaviour to use the incorrect format specifiers when bits were masked away

Tags: c, printf, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, format-specifiers

If I have some imaginary `uint32_t` and I am interested in looking at each byte is it undefined behaviour to use the format specifier for a `uint8_t` rather than a `uint32_t`. See below for an example of what I mean.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void)
{
    uint32_t myInt = 0xFF8BA712;
    
    printf("1: %" PRIu8 ", 2: %" PRIu8 ", 3: %" PRIu8 ", 4: %" PRIu8 "\n", myInt & 0xFF, (myInt >> 8) & 0xFF, (myInt >> 16) & 0xFF, (myInt >> 24) & 0xFF);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Using the compilation command: `gcc test.c -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c2x` I receive no compilation warnings or errors. This seems to me like it should be OK. However, I do use code like this in a codebase that works with images that have a bit depth of 32bpp and I often need to extract individual bytes from a whole pixel in order to work with them. Therefore, I would like to avoid this undefined behaviour regarding printing these bytes if it exists.

Comment: That is fine. Your mask to `0xff` limits the bits to `8` and that corresponds to `PRIu8`. (now you can tidy things as specified in the answer, but it not UB without a cast)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clang-cl compiler (in Visual Studio 2019) gives four of the following warnings for your code:

> warning : format specifies type 'unsigned char' but the argument has
> type 'unsigned int' [-Wformat]

Now, although *strictly speaking*, passing an argument that is not the appropriate type for its corresponding format specifier **is** undefined behaviour, the arguments to the `printf` function will, in any case, be promoted to their respective `int` equivalents in this case. From [this C11 Draft Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> ##### 7.21.6.1 The `fprintf` function
>
> …
> 7     The length modifiers and their meanings are:
>        **hh**     Specifies that a following **`d`**, **`i`**, **`o`**, **`u`**, **`x`**, or **`X`** conversion specifier applies
>                  to a **`signed char`** or **`unsigned char`** argument (the argument will have been
>                  promoted according to the integer promotions, but its value shall be converted
>                  to **`signed char`** or **`unsigned char`** before printing); …

You can remove the warnings by casting each argument (to `uint8_t`) but the excerpt above suggests (to me, at least) that this would make no real difference:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void)
{
    uint32_t myInt = 0xFF8BA712;
    printf("1: %" PRIu8 ", 2: %" PRIu8 ", 3: %" PRIu8 ", 4: %" PRIu8 "\n",
        (uint8_t)(myInt & 0xFF), (uint8_t)((myInt >> 8) & 0xFF), (uint8_t)((myInt >> 16) & 0xFF),
        (uint8_t)((myInt >> 24) & 0xFF));

    return 0;
}
```

---

Note that, on my system, `PRIu8` is defined as `"hhu"` and `uint8_t` is equivalent to `unsigned char` – and this is likely to be the case on many other platforms.

Comment: Hmm, must be a `cl.exe` thing, because `clang version 12.0.1` on Linux produces no such warning... (but I agree with your reasoning)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin MSVC itself (cl.exe) gives no warning, even when running its static analyzer.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend to cast all values to `uint8_t` first, both for clearness and for consistency (i.e.: `PRIu8` requires values of type `uint8_t`):

```c
// something like this
uint32_t x = 5;
printf("%" PRIu8 "\n", (uint8_t) (x >> 24));
```

But if you don't cast, it should continue to work. Why? Because values of type `uint8_t` (probable a.k.a. for `unsigned char`) are promoted to `int` when you use them in a variadic function. Indeed, on my platform, `"%" PRIu8` is an alias for `%u` (i.e.: the format specifier for `unsigned int`). However, the size of an `int` is implementation-defined, so you may have nasty bugs if you don't correctly cast your values to the correct specifier (i.e.: use `uint8_t` for `PRIu8`, etc).

An example of code that may not work if you don't cast:

```c
uint64_t x = 5;
printf("%" PRIu8 "\n", x >> 56);
```